# How to set sound for caller after receiving call?

Tags: iphone

i am working on such project in which after detecting the call on iphone i will receive it and the i will play sound on it which will be audible to caller only...can anyone help me out to do this or plz tell me that is it possible for iphone ios 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

For apps that comply with the SDK agreement (submittable to the App store), you can't detect or receive phone calls.  They are outside an app's secure sandbox.

Comment: if i want to work for an autoanswering machin is there any solution available??